# Filebeat fails to start when output is set to file

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I am quite new to filebeat and the ELK stack. After succesfully building a Filebeat, Elastic and Kibana stack indexing apache access logfiles, I wanted to use Filebeat to send output to a file for testing purposes. However, I keep running into an error. Filebeat starts and then immediately exits again because it is looking for elastic.

The relevant part of the logfile is below.

```
2020-02-20T16:19:40.794+0100    WARN    beater/filebeat.go:152  Filebeat is unable to load the Ingest Node pipelines for the configured modules because the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled. If you have already loaded the Ingest Node pipelines or are using Logstash pipelines, you can ignore this warning.
2020-02-20T16:19:40.794+0100    ERROR   instance/beat.go:916    Exiting: Index management requested but the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled
```

Below is the filebeat.yml that is used.

```
#=========================== Filebeat inputs =============================

filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - C:\Some\folder\*

#============================= Filebeat modules ===============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: C:\another\folder\*.yml
  reload.enabled: true

#------------------------------- File output -----------------------------------
output.file:
  enabled: true
  path: 'C:\Yet\another\folder\'
  filename: filebeat
```

I have also configured an apache.yml

```
- module: apache
  # Access logs
  access:
    enabled: true

    # Set custom paths for the log files. If left empty,
    # Filebeat will choose the paths depending on your OS.
    var.paths: ['C:\Some\Folder\2\Access*']
```

Filebeat keeps asking for the elastic output to be configured, but only one output can be configured at a time.
Is there a some option I need to set?
I am using Elastic stack 7.5

Answer (score 0):

Probably Filebeat is trying to [load template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-template.html) into Elasticsearch, but Elasticsearch output is not configured.

Disable automatic template loading  by adding following config to filebeat.yml file

```
setup.template.enabled: false
```

Hopefully, this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I added "setup.template.enabled: false" to the filebeat.yml. Unfortunately, this did not solve it. I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, kibana needs to be running for the output.file option to work.
After I started kibana.bat and ran .\filebeat.exe setup --dashboards. The error disappeared and filebeat could set its output to file.